# Populate text string with the title attribute

Tags: jquery

I need the information that displays as the title attribute to reflect in the text string, for example, in the below I would want "Make this the string" to display rather than "What is current".

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="ellipsis" title="make this the string">What is current</td>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the only thing I have been able to find does the opposite:

```
$('.ellipsis').each(function() {
$(this).prop('title', $(this).text());
});
```

In the above, the current text will replace the title, any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Here is the fiddle if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/2U9S8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you had with your existing code is that you were setting the `title` property to be equivalent to the text of the element, using the `prop()` method, rather than setting the text content to be equivalent to the `title` property.

Instead, then, I'd suggest:

```
$('td.ellipsis').text(function(){
    return this.title;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2U9S8/2/).

References:

- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Even better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

To update the title you will use `.attr` instead of prop.
Try this:

```
$(this).text($(this).attr('title'));
```

Using this, you can update the attribute `title`'s value, by getting its own text.

Answer (score 0):

You just have the code backward. Try this:

```
$('.ellipsis').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).prop('title'));
});
```